# Lambda to populate Map

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-8

I am trying to fill up a map with words and the number of their occurrences. I am trying to write a lambda to do it, like so:

```
Consumer<String> wordCount = word -> map.computeIfAbsent(word, (w) -> (new Integer(1) + 1).intValue());
```

`map` is `Map<String, Integer>`. It should just insert the word in the map as a key if it is absent and if it is present it should increase its integer value by 1. This one is not correct syntax-wise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't increment the count using `computeIfAbsent`, since it will only be computed the first time.

You probably meant:

```
map.compute(word, (w, i) -> i == null ? 1 : i + 1);
```

Comment: You mean `map.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum)`

Comment: @shmosel This is even a better option, consider posting as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't compile because you can't call a method on a primitive:

```
new Integer(1) -> 1  // unboxing was applied
(1 + 1).intValue()   // incorrect
```

I would write it with [`Map#put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,V)) and [`Map#getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)):

```
Consumer<String> consumer = word -> map.put(word, map.getOrDefault(word, 0) + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what `Collector`s are for.

Assuming you have some `Stream<String> words`:

```
Map<String, Long> countedWords = words
    .collect(Collectors
        .groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            Collectors.counting());
```