# Set counting items

Tags: java, collections, set

I wonder if there are any java collection counting occurences in a set.

Since it just stores the references once and gets the number of times it was added it saves space but allows you to know the number of times it was added.
It also saves space in case you need to know if there are available items or not.

For example:

```
Set<Object> counterSet = new Set<Object>();

counterSet.add("Hello");
counterSet.add("world");
counterSet.add("Hello");

counterSet.numberOfInstances("Hello"); //returns 2
counterSet.numberOfInstances("world"); //returns 1
```

I've been looking for it but I don't find a collection like this, could you tell me the best way to do it?

Comment: Use a `HashMap<Object,Integer>`.

Comment: You can do it this way right, but then you have to check if the HashMap contains the key, is the way I do it, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: And how would your fiction method `numberOfInstances` respond if not having the object in the set?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose it would return 0

Comment: You can find some solutions using Map here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790737

Comment: And a `Map.get()` returns `null`, having the same meaning. And by the way: A `Set` only contains 1 of each object!

Comment: Cool example with lambdas @Eran, thank you

Comment: Thats the idea @Seelenvirtuose, contains it just once and a counter, this way you save space in case you use a list you would take more space than needed, in case you do it with a map it also works but you have to code by yourselve the get method, Bedla gave the answer I was looking for, thank you all for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MultiSet](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiSet.html) from [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).

> Defines a collection that counts the number of times an object appears in the collection.
>   Suppose you have a MultiSet that contains {a, a, b, c}. Calling getCount(Object) on a would return 2, while calling uniqueSet() would return {a, b, c}.

See this example:

```
public class MultiSetTest {
    @Test
    public void testMultiSet(){
        MultiSet<String> counterSet = new HashMultiSet<>();
        counterSet.add("Hello");
        counterSet.add("world");
        counterSet.add("Hello");

        Assert.assertEquals(2, counterSet.getCount("Hello"));
        Assert.assertEquals(1, counterSet.getCount("world"));
        Assert.assertEquals(0, counterSet.getCount("somethingMissing"));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do couterSet.getCount("newString"); it returns 0?

Comment: @DavidMarciel Yes. Thanks for suggestion, I have added assert for this case.

Answer (score 4):

A Set doesn't allow duplicates. Instead look into using a `Map<String, Integer>` or a `List<String>` and then use `Collections.frequency` to get the count.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Bag](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/package-summary.html) type from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
Bag<String> bag = Bags.mutable.with("Hello", "world", "Hello");
Assert.assertEquals(2, bag.occurrencesOf("Hello"));
Assert.assertEquals(1, bag.occurrencesOf("world"));
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.